# Can you authenticate the Twitter API within the URL?

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to authenticate the Twitter API through a URL in a web browser?

ex. https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi**&secret_token=234234234234**

I've been researching this for quite a while and haven't found a definite answer.

And if so, where in the docs would the names of the variables be that I need to authenticate via a URL?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how the Twitter API works.  You need to construct a valid OAuth authorization string and include it as the  header in your request.

See [Authorizing a Request](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests) in the Twitter REST API documentation.